# reformat my repetitive code into a while or for loop for minesweeper game in python using oop

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, oop, while-loop

So for the game mine sweeper when you click a box with 0 surrounding mines not only is that cell revealed but all surrounding cells. I want to make my code so that if there is then another 0 that was revealed all cells around that 0 are also revealed.

ie if there are 2 0s together (side by side say) when clicked not just the 8 surrounding the one clicked are revealed but the 8 plus the 3 revealed by the other 0. (assuming not near edge)

Im using oop and this is the Cell class and the cells are the instances.

```
def single_click(self, event):
```

- function when the cell is single clicked (reveal mine or number of surrounding mines)

```
        if self.is_mine:
            self.show_mine()
```

- if the cell is a mine its a revealed. if not ...
  (surrounded_mines is the number of neighbouring mines

```
        else:
            if self.surrounded_mines == 0:
                for cell in self.surrounded_cells:
                    cell.show_cell()
```

- first lot of neighbouring cells are revealed if cell clicked is 0 ^

```
                    if cell.surrounded_mines == 0:
                        for cell2 in cell.surrounded_cells:
                            cell2.show_cell()
```

- second lot of neighbouring cells are revealed if a 0 was revealed in the stem before

```
                            if cell2.surrounded_mines == 0:
                                for cell3 in cell2.surrounded_cells:
                                    cell3.show_cell()
```

- and again

```
            self.show_cell()
```

and i could do this a few times because its unlikely there will be that many 0s together but id rather know how to code it properly.

Im usually ok with while loops but im just a bit confused as I dont know what id do for the condition.

If there is a better way to format my code id love to hear!

while im at it im using the tkiner package for the GUI and since i dont have a left/right click mouse (mac) I wanted to play the game using single and double clicks however I havnt been able to find out how to double click without also calling the single click.

THANKS!

Comment: Sounds like a good case for recursion. Think of a function that reveals all cells that boarder a zero, collects the newly revealed zeros, and then calls itself on the new list, and then calls itself on the new list, and then calls itself on the new list. Until no more zeros are revealed. Here's a free book on the topic (Scroll down below the "buy me" links) https://inventwithpython.com/recursion/

Answer (score 0):

Here's a recursive solution. You might need to tweak it to suit your needs.

```
import random

# 10x10 mine field
# "-" = not clicked, " " = cleared, "m" = mine
game = [['-'] * 10 for _ in range(10)]

# Returns r,c of every space around row,col
def get_surrounding_spaces(row, col):
    spaces = []
    for r in range(row-1, row+2):
        for c in range(col-1, col+2):
            if r >= 0 and r < len(game) and c >= 0 and c < len(game[r]) and (r,c) != (row,col):
                spaces.append((r,c,))
    return spaces

# Checks the cell. If it has no mines around it, clear all around.
# Calls recursively on those
def clear_space(row, col):
    if game[row][col] != '-': return
    game[row][col] = ' '
    surrounding_spaces = get_surrounding_spaces(row, col)
    has_mines = any(True for r,c in surrounding_spaces if game[r][c] == 'm')
    if not has_mines:
        # Recursive clear surrounding spaces
        for r,c in surrounding_spaces:
            clear_space(r, c)

# Helper function to print minefield
def print_game():
    print(f"  {' '.join(f'{x:2}' for x in range(10))}")
    for i,row in enumerate(game):
        print(f"{i:<2} {'  '.join(row)}")

# 15 or so random mines
for _ in range(15):
    r = random.randint(0, len(game)-1)
    c = random.randint(0, len(game[0])-1)
    game[r][c] = 'm'

# Test
print_game()
r,c = map(int, input("row,col: ").split(','))
clear_space(r, c)
print_game()
```

Sample run:

```
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  m  -  -  -  -  -  m  -  -  -
1  -  -  -  m  -  -  -  -  -  -
2  -  -  -  -  -  -  m  -  m  -
3  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
4  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -  -
5  -  -  -  -  m  -  -  -  -  -
6  -  -  -  -  m  -  -  -  -  -
7  m  -  -  -  -  -  m  -  m  -
8  -  -  -  -  m  -  m  -  m  -
9  -  -  -  m  -  -  m  -  -  -
row,col: 3,2
   0  1  2  3  4  5  6  7  8  9
0  m  -  -  -  -  -  m  -  -  -
1           m  -  -  -  -  -  -
2                    m  -  m  -
3                    -  -  -  -
4                    -  -  -  -
5              m  -  -  -  -  -
6              m  -  -  -  -  -
7  m           -  -  m  -  m  -
8  -           m  -  m  -  m  -
9  -  -  -  m  -  -  m  -  -  -
```